# is it possible to have a input argument as output in JNI?

Tags: function, java-native-interface, arguments

is it possible to have a input argument as output argument in JNI ?

Suppose I have :

```
void average(jint n1,jint n2,jint av);
```

`av` as output and why not input.

Answer (score 1):

Not in that fashion, no.

In order for the callee to modify an argument, it must have a reference (i.e. pointer) to that argument.  `jint` and other primitives are passed by value, which means that the value of the argument is passed from one location (memory or register) to another.  Any changes made by the callee to that argument are made to the last element in the chain, which obviously has no effect on the places it was copied from.

In order to have an argument "modified", you have to pass a reference (pointer) to it instead.    The most straightforward way of doing this in Java is to pass a single-element primitive array, and have the callee replace the first element with the "returned" value.

It's usually just easier to return the value, or an aggregate object which contains multiple return values.